# looking for more info on EIO error returned by readdir_r () on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, runtime-error

On Mac OS X 10.6.8, some C code that calls `readdir_r()` sometimes gets an I/O error 5 (EIO) returned.  I've seen this just a few times, always on external USB drives.  Each time I've seen it, if I immediately cd to the parent direction and do an `ls`, I appear to see all the files.  And, if I re-run the C program that saw the error, it will run fine.

On some platforms, when one gets an error like EIO, there's something else you can call that gives you *much* more detailed error information (e.g., hperrmsg on MPE/iX, which accesses the per-process error stack).  Is there something similar on OS X?

I guess I'm assuming that the error is `false`

```
i = readdir_r (dirp, &dire, &dire_ptr);

save_errno = errno;

if (i)
{
    if (i == EACCES)

    ...

    else
    {
        my_perror (save_errno, "readdir_r failed: ");

        espout4 ("readdir_r returned %s; errno = %s, dire_ptr = %s; parent = %s\n",
                num64 (i), num64 (save_errno), fmt_p (dire_ptr), parent_dir);

        espout1 ("   (ERROR: readdir_r failed here, errno %s)\n", num64 (save_errno));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, a week later...

I've determined that the combo of the Macally case (model G-S350SU)
and the Western Digital drive was causing sporadic problems.  I noticed that the WD SATA connector didn't mate tightly with the Macally socket.  Using a Seagate drive with the case was fine, and using the WD drive in a different case was fine.

Of course, I'd still like to be able to get better / more detailed error information in my programs :)